# What is the fastest way to farm Mimics in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

Mimics look like chests and seem to spawn relatively rarely. Is there an efficient way to farm them for their drops?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most efficient way to farm them is to make a farm for them, of course! But while it's the most efficient way, it's still not very efficient. You could be looking at several minutes between drops.

The general setup for a Mimic farm is quite simple:

1. Find yourself a mountain, or generally a place with natural dirt walls that isn't too deep (else you'll get golden Mimics with double health).
2. Dig down and and make a lava pit. Make several 3-high tunnels to the left and right of it.
3. Set up Dart Traps aimed at the ground of each tunnel. Wire them to a 3 Second Timer.
4. Activate the Timer and set up camp in the middle so that the Mimics will fall into the lava pit.

What happens: When a Mimic spawns in one of the tunnels off-screen, a Dart Trap will give it a poke, which sends it hopping towards you and ultimately, the lava pit.

Since this isn't a novel concept, here's two designs that I totally stole from other people.

- [design 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z26ep.png) ([source](http://www.reddit.com/r/Terraria/comments/olm7w/since_others_were_asking_mimic_farm_that_actually/))
- [design 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzh71.png) ([source](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/mimic-farming-during-blood-moon.73405/))

Of course, there are also the general tips that apply to every grinder setup:

- Hold a Water Candle while idling.
- Chug Battle Potions.
- If other enemies congregate around your location, make another lava pit to get rid of them — they'll hog the NPC spawn slots.

Answer (score 1):

go to the jungle temple. mimics have an increased spawn rate there

Answer (score 0):

Make a long tunnel with dart traps shooting down it with 3 second time place water candles and drink battle potion and hit any mimics that come towards you